# When accessed differently, get different version of the same model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

When I access a model 'Location' in two different ways, I get two different versions of the model.

One has `location_id: nil`, one has `location_id: 3`

```
2.0.0-p481 :054 > e.shifts.last.location
 => #<Location id: 35, location_id: 3, name: "Hoxton Hotel", address_1: "81 Great Eastern St", postcode: "EC2A 3HU", lng: -0.0827515, lat: 51.5256224, locatable_id: 13, locatable_type: "Shift", created_at: "2015-09-10 09:59:55", updated_at: "2015-09-11 10:18:41", radius: 5.0> 

2.0.0-p481 :052 > Location.find(35)
  Location Load (0.8ms)  SELECT  "locations".* FROM "locations" WHERE "locations"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 35]]
 => #<Location id: 35, location_id: nil, name: "Hoxton Hotel", address_1: "81 Great Eastern St", postcode: "EC2A 3HU", lng: -0.0827515, lat: 51.5256224, locatable_id: 13, locatable_type: "Shift", created_at: "2015-09-10 09:59:55", updated_at: "2015-09-11 10:18:41", radius: 5.0>
```

The model has this self-referential association:

```
has_many :children, class_name: "Location", foreign_key: "location_id", dependent: :nullify
belongs_to :parent, class_name: "Location", foreign_key: "location_id"
```

The issue is that when I do Location.find(3).children, not all of the children are coming back.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that ActiveRecord will behave correctly with that name for the foreign key. Maybe you can try with better naming of the association, with something like `parent`

```
has_many :children, class_name: "Location", foreign_key: "parent_id", dependent: :nullify
belongs_to :parent, class_name: "Location", foreign_key: "parent_id"
```

By the way, what is `e.shifts`? Can you try with your model as it is right now to do `Location.last` and see if the result is the same?

Answer (score 0):

That's because in a many:one relationship, the relationship id is at the 'one' end, as it is implemented as a type of foreign key on the underlying table.

I think you might want a self-referential many:many relationship, which is achieved by having a joining relation which is implemented as a table with the id relationships.

```
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :location_relationships, :foreign_key => "child_id", :class_name => "LocationRelationship"
   has_many :children, :through => :location_relationships
end

class LocationRelationship < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :location, :foreign_key => "location_id", :class_name => "Location"
   belongs_to :child, :foreign_key => "child_id", :class_name => "Location"  
end
```

Comment: I don't get it... I'm looking for a many-one relationship. Surely, in the underlying table, location 35 either has or doesn't have a location_id of 3?